# vert.x javascript winston logging

Tags: javascript, vert.x, winston

when I import winston module in my vert.x javascript(3.4.1) version application it throws the error as such..Is it a version mismatch error??

Caused by: :141:6 Error: Cannot find module ./winston
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeError.initException(NativeError.ja
va:137)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeError.(NativeError.java:102)

```
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeError.<init>(NativeError.java:106)

    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeError.<init>(NativeError.java:110)

    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeError.constructor(NativeError.java
```

Comment: Make sure `npm install` is done, show us some code.

Comment: i have done npm install but while and i have also installed winston 0.1.0 but still it doesnt work..code: var winston=require('winston'); error:           org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: missing ; before statement (file:/H:/manuvertx/vert.x-2.1.5/vert.x-2.1.5/bin/log.js#7)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError(DefaultErrorReporter.java:77)